# Find the rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the matrix $G=(I_{16},A)$ where $A=\left( \begin{array}_
J&I_4&I_4&I_4  \\
I_4&J&I_4&I_4 \\
I_4&I_4&J&I_4 \\
I_4&I_4&I_4&J  \end{array} \right)$ and $J=\left( \begin{array}_
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1 \end{array} \right)$.

It's difficult at least for me to find the rank of this matrix and more difficult to find the minimum number of the dependent vectors.

Do you have any thoughts of how to do it? Any quick tricks?

Thank you!

Comment: source of the problem? what techniques have you been studying that led up to this?

Comment: fine. suggest you do the problem in detail for each block $m$ by $m$ for, say, $m \leq 4,$ and $k$ by $k$ blocks, so the whole thing is $mk$ by $mk,$ for $mk$ not as big as 16. maybe some patterns will emerge.

Comment: @WillJagy, this matrix is a generator matrix of a code. I don't have the code in detail though

Comment: Well, if it is important, you will do what I said, examine easier cases of the same general pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a quick trick... First and trivial note is that $A=A^T$. Second, it is a very simple matrix, ones and zeros. So for 2 columns to be dependent, the need to be identical. I can't see any identical columns, so i would say its a full rank matrix

Comment: correct about the $A=A^t$ but you are wrong about dependency. Depedency is not only between two vectors

Comment: You are right about it, my bad. I just noted that we need to find rang(G) and not rank(A). In G there are dependencies. (take column(18) = column(17) - column(5) + column(6) ). So G is definatelly not full rank...